# What is the best method to copy all matching text from a web page?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web, macros

**Background**
I have a live web dashboard for ticket numbers and their status updates. Each update and case number are in separate rows on this web page. To make this dashboard useful, I have to save it as offline HTML and import it into excel to copy one row of data like all case numbers.

**Goal**
How do I search for a matching string on a page and copy all to clipboard in separate lines? EG, all my case numbers match the first two digits like “12.......”
If I can manage to figure that out, I can make use of text in tools easier like Trello etc.

Comment: You need to try something at your own first and then we'll help you!

Comment: So will I learn all languages and test them out? I don’t know languages that could do this which is why I asked for help. If I was told - learn Ruby and do this, then come back to me on StackOverflow - that would be a lot more helpful.   I’m sorry - but I did research this before making a post. I’m so lost how to do it - that I don’t know which tool I should use or learn for doing it. Hopefully that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this with Python:

```
import re
import requests

text = input("Enter text: ")

url = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69691849/what-is-the-best-method-to-copy-all-matching-text-from-a-web-page').text
page = re.findall(text, url)

for i in page:
    print(i)
```

I don't think you'd be able to copy all the output, however you could just copy the output from command prompt. It's unclear what you are trying to fully achieve here.

Output:

[image]

Output with array ( `print(page)` ):

[image]

Comment: Thanks insula. This is perfect.  I wasn’t sure which tool would be best for doing this. I am interested in picking up Python after this post

Comment: @IanO'Loughlin No problem! Python is an excellent language, I recommend learning it from W3Schools or freecodecamp :)